# Using PHP arrays to return CSS code

Tags: php, arrays, css, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to use arrays to return a specific CSS code, but I haven't found an automatic way to make the value of the array change according to the array. Here's what i'm trying to do:

```
$css = array(
    "bgcolor" => array(
        "wh" => array(* => "background-color:rgba(255,255,255,*);"),
        "bk" => array(* => "background-color:rgba(0,0,0,*);")
    ),
    "textcolor" => array(
        "wh" => "color: #FFFFFF;",
        "bk" => "color: #000000;"
     ),
    "fade" => array(
        "wh" => array(* => "box-shadow:#FFF 0px 0px *px;"),
        "bk" => array(* => "box-shadow:#000 0px 0px *px;")
     )
);
```

I'm using the * just to illustrate what i'm trying to achieve. This is what the code is supposed to return:

```
$css["bgcolor"]["wh"][0.5]; // print background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
$css["textcolor"]["wh"]; // print color: #FFFFFF;
$css["fade"]["wh"][100]; // print box-shadow:#FFF 0px 0px 100px;
```

I don't know if what I want is possible, but I think it is, I just dont know how. :D

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is use arrays to generate values. That is not possible. azcn2503's reply below is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PHP 5.3 or greater, you can achieve this by using anonymous functions like so:

```
<?php

    $css = array(
        'bgcolor' => array(
            'wh' => function($s) {
                return 'background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, ' . $s . ');';
            },
            'bk' => function($s) {
                return 'background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, ' . $s . ');';
            }
        )
    );

    echo($css['bgcolor']['bk'](0.25)); // Returns rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)
    echo(PHP_EOL);
    echo($css['bgcolor']['wh'](0.75)); // Returns rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75)

?>
```

I hope this is what you were after.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Only a minor correction:

Where is 
    return 'background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, ' . $s . ')';
should be
    return 'background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, ' . $s . ');';

Thanks mate

Comment: Oops, I missed the semicolon! Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Using a function

```
<?php

echo getStyle("bgcolor", "wh", 0.5);
echo getStyle("textcolor", "wh", 0.5);
echo getStyle("fade", "wh", 100);

function getStyle($style, $color, $px = 0) {

    $css = array(
        "bgcolor" => array(
            "wh" => "background-color:rgba(255,255,255,*px);",
            "bk" => "background-color:rgba(0,0,0,*px);"
        ),
        "textcolor" => array(
            "wh" => "color: #FFFFFF;",
            "bk" => "color: #000000;"
         ),
        "fade" => array(
            "wh" => "box-shadow:#FFF 0px 0px *px;",
            "bk" => "box-shadow:#000 0px 0px *px;"
         )
    );
    return str_replace("*", $px, $css[$style][$color]);
}
```